# How do I label all Tasks associated with the same Order # where a specific Task is also part of that order?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm dealing with an Excel file similar to this (changed/simplified for privacy):

[image]

| Order # | Task | Car was washed as part of this order? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Review | Yes |
| 1 | Change tires | Yes |
| 1 | Wash car | Yes |
| 2 | Review | No |
| 2 | Change tires | No |
| 2 | Change Oil | No |

Different **Tasks** can share the same **Order #**.

I need a formula to populate the third column (yellow in image) with "Yes" if a **Task** is part of an **Order #** that includes the **Task** "Wash car", or return "No" if it isn't.

I have searched for a solution online without success.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a progression of 5 formulas. Each formula is based off the one(s) that preceded it.  Hopefully progressing in this way makes the later ones easier to understand.

### <sub><sup>[ Formula 1 of 5 ]</sup></sub>   Foundational Formula

```
=IFERROR(IF(
   MATCH(A2:A7,FILTER(A2:A7,B2:B7="Wash car"),0),
   "yes"),"no")
```

1. [IF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) function uses [MATCH](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) as its `logical_test`.

   - [MATCH](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) uses each order in turn as the `search_key`
   - The `range` argument is populated using the [FILTER](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) function to return a list of orders where the task is "Wash car"
2. The [IF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) function's `value_if_true` argument is `"Yes"`
3. `value_if_false` is omitted as the `logical_test` used can only return `TRUE` or `#N/A`
4. [IFERROR](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611) replaces errors by `"No"`

<sub><sup>**[ Formula 1 of 5 ]   Foundational Formula**</sup></sub>
[image]

#### <sub><sup>[ Formula 2 of 5 ]</sup></sub>   Ignore Blank Rows

```
=IF(A2:A7<>0, IFERROR(IF(
   MATCH(A2:A7,FILTER(A2:A7,B2:B7="Wash car"),0),
   "Yes"),"No"),"")
```

1. To ignore blank rows, an [IF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) function is added with `value<>0` as its `logical_test`.  It will return:

   - `TRUE` for any cell containing a non-zero number as well as any text string, even those containing digits. eg. `("0"<>0)=TRUE`
   - `FALSE` for the number `0` as well as empty cells which Excel coerces to zero. eg. if `OR(ISBLANK(A1),A1=0)` then `(A1<>0)=FALSE`
2. The **Basic Formula** is used as the `value_if_true`
3. `value_if_false` is an empty string `""`. 
   <sup>This approach skips returning `"No"` while preventing row offset from gaps in the data.</sup>

<sub><sup>**[ Formula 2 of 5 ]   Ignore Blank Rows**</sup></sub>
[image]

#### <sub><sup>[ Formula 3 of 5 ]</sup></sub>   Formula on Heading Row

Moving the formula to the heading row might prevent it from being overwritten.

```
=VSTACK("Wash on Order?",
  IF(A2:A7<>0, IFERROR(IF(
     MATCH(A2:A7,FILTER(A2:A7,B2:B7="Wash car"),0),
     "Yes"),"No"),""))
```

1. [VSTACK](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vstack-function-a4b86897-be0f-48fc-adca-fcc10d795a9c) allows stacking arrays vertically
2. The first array used was the title `"Wash on Order?"`
3. The second array is the previous formula.

<sub><sup>**[ Formula 3 of 5 ]   Formula on Heading Row**</sup></sub>
[image]

#### <sub><sup>[ Formula 4 of 5 ]</sup></sub>   LET Function Added

While [LET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) alone doesn't add a lot to the previous formula, it is applied in this step to clarify the transformation. As formulas get more complex the usefulness of [LET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) become more clear.

```
=LET(rng,A2:B7,
   a,DROP(rng,,-1), b,DROP(rng,,1),
   VSTACK("Wash on Order?",
     IF(a<>0, IFERROR(IF(
       MATCH(a, FILTER(a, b="Wash car"), 0),
       "Yes"), "No"), "")))
```

1. The [LET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) function allows storing values and formulas in variables for reuse.  This can reduce code repetition and formula length, and can also make complex formulas easier to understand and manage.
2. The source range is stored in `rng`.
3. Column A `a` and Column B `b` are returned using [DROP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/drop-function-1cb4e151-9e17-4838-abe5-9ba48d8c6a34) to dispatch the unnecessary column.
4. `a` and `b` are now used instead of `A2:A7` and `B2:B7` in the formula.

<sub><sup>**[ Formula 4 of 5 ]   LET Function Added**</sup></sub>
[image]

#### <sub><sup>[ Formula 5 of 5 ]</sup></sub>   Automatically Size the Range

Allows the data to grow without needing to modify the formula. Accepts full columns and then sizes the array as needed based on the populated data.  The value of [LET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) is on full display.

```
=LET(rng,A:B,  
  arr,DROP(FILTER(rng, ROW(rng)<=
    MAX((rng<>0)*(ROW(rng)))),1),
  a,DROP(arr,,-1), b,DROP(arr,,1),
  VSTACK("Wash on Order?",
    IF(a<>0, IFERROR(IF(MATCH(a,
      FILTER(a, b="Wash car"), 0),
      "yes"),"no"),"")))
```

1. [FILTER](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) returns an array `arr` of the rows whose row number is `<=` that of the last row containing an order ID.
2. The last row is calculated by applying [MAX](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/max-function-e0012414-9ac8-4b34-9a47-73e662c08098) to an array of row numbers whose rows also contain a non-zero value.  The asterisk `*` is the 'and' operator: `MAX(ROW(rng)*rng<>0)`
3. This resulting array includes the heading (row 1), the orders as well as any gaps.  The gaps are included to ensure that intentional or accidental gaps do not cause results to be offset from the original range.
4. The [DROP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/drop-function-1cb4e151-9e17-4838-abe5-9ba48d8c6a34) function is used to remove the heading row. Alternatively, this can be achieved by adding the [FILTER](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) condition `ROW(rng)<>1`

<sub><sup>**[ Formula 5 of 5 ]   Automatically Size the Range**</sup></sub>
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following solution appears to meet the goals set forth in your sample data.

1. In a blank column `C`, concatenate `A` and `B` columns with `=concat(A2,B2)` (in cell `C2`) for each row.
2. In a blank column `D`, add the following formula starting at `D2`. This is an array formula so you will need to press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` at the same time to make it work.

   `=IF(OR($A$1:$A$6=A1)*(OR($C$1:$C$6=CONCAT(A1,"Wash car"))),"Yes","No")`
3. Copy `D2` to the remaining rows.

---

If I am overlooking something (which I feel like I may be doing since my sample data set is so limited), please let me know and I will try to correct it. If this solution ends up solving your problem, please mark it as an answer.